# .Net Framework installation statistics

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, .net-framework

I have tried my best to find something relevant, but failed. I quit Windows development almost 8 years ago, so my knowledge is pretty outdated. Back then there were still huge amounts of Windows machines without .NET framework installed. Have something changed since then? Did MSFT begin to preinstall it? Maybe there is a way to view installation statistics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See list below

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/)

.
[image]

"When the .NET Framework is installed as a part of the OS, it does not appear in the Programs and Features (or Add/Remove Programs) control panel.  The following is a complete list of which version of the .NET Framework is included in which version of the OS:" That being said it can be turned on or off in the "Turn Windows features on or off" section of Programs and Features.

.

"In addition, the .NET Framework shipped with the following versions of Windows but not as truly integrated OS components"

[image]

Comment: I'm slightly confused: "includes the .NET Framework XXX as an OS component, and it is installed by default". What does it mean? Can it be "an OS component", but not installed by default? Also "Windows 7 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 3.5.1 as an OS component.  This means you will get the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 plus a few post 3.5 SP1 bug fixes.  3.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel." - is it installed in a  clean windows installation or not?

Comment: Yeah it a bit confusing, they should have said by using the "Turn Windows Features on or off  " in Programs and Features. Features would be components of the OS which includes NF. Yes it is installed as a component of a clean install.

Comment: Should also be noted that the versions listed here are only what's installed by-default - newer versions can be installed via (automatic) Windows Updates depending on your update config. e.g. most up-to-date Win7 machines will have .NET 4.5+ on them despite it not being the included version.

Answer (score 5):

> Back then there were still huge amounts of windows machines without
>   .net framework installed.

Windows XP Windows Vista does not come with .NET Framework preinstalled.  Windows 8+ does come with a version preinstalled.

> Maybe there is a way to view installation statistics?

You will have to collect this information yourself, or base your estimations, on the usage of each edition of Windows.

> Did Microsoft begin to pre-install it?

Yes

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Release_history)

Comment: Can anyone explain their downvote to me?